# Select item by array-key in mustache-template?

Tags: javascript, templates, mustache

I have a couple of tumblr-posts that I wish to output using mustache.

In tumblr, posts come in an array with different sizes. I always want to use `alt_sizes[2]`

I don't know if it's possible to refence arrays by id. My current solution is to pick it out in advance like this:

```
height.photos[z].columnPhoto = post.photos[z].alt_sizes[2]
```

and later in my template I can target the data like this:

```
{{#photos}}
  {{columnPhoto.url}}
{{/photos}}
```

Phtotos is also an array I'm looping through

Is it possible to target `alt_sizes[2]` straight from the template?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the "dot"-annotation, like this:
{{#photos}}
  {{alt_sizes.2.url}}
{{/photos}}